# Error when using removeChild to remove multiple form inputs.

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

I keep getting the error when trying to remove all the checked checkboxes in a form.

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined"
```

When running this

```
// remove only the 'checked' tasks
function remChecked() {
var nList = document.forms["theForm"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, l = nList.length; i < l; i = i + 1) {
        var list = nList[i];
        if (list.checked == true) {
            list.parentNode.removeChild(list);
        }
    }
}

var el3 = document.getElementById("removeChecked");
el3.addEventListener("click", remChecked, false);
```

The error refers to the line with the "if" on it.

It works ok when there's only one checkbox input with a `checked=true` property.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are all of your input elements checkbox or radio buttons? if any are hidden, text, password etc. they won't have a checked property.

Comment: You are also pre-determining the length of your list of input's but nList is a **live** NodeList... depending how many items you remove/meet your condition you may end up with an index out of bounds error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When removing elements from a **live** NodeList you will want to remove them in reverse order.

```
function remChecked() {
  //nList is a live NodeList
  var nList = document.forms["theForm"].getElementsByTagName("input");
  //loop backwards...
  for(var i=nList.length-1;i>-1;i--){
    var list = nList[i];
    if(list.checked == true){
        list.parentNode.removeChild(list);
    }
  }
}
var el3 = document.getElementById("removeChecked");
    el3.addEventListener("click", remChecked, false);
```

If there were say 12 checkboxes originally... and half (6) were checked.
When you loop from 0 to "length" if you delete an item the length shrinks... thus by the time you get to 11 (n-1) there isn't a matching element.

By working in reverse... (11 to 0) if you delete 11 it isn't an issue because the next iteration is 10... then 9, then 8,...

Comment: Yes, that's it! It works perfectly. "Working in reverse" I would have never thought of that but it seems so obvious now in hindsight! Thank You.

Comment: Or `while (nList.length) nList[0].parentNode.removeChild(nList[0]);` or `var i = nList.length; while (i--) nList[0].parentNode.removeChild(nList[0]);` and so on.